# CodeChef- how to read input file

Tags: java

Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.
Example

Input:
1
2
88
42
99

Output:
1
2
88

Its says the input is coming from standard input. I'm using Java. I understand what to do if say I had the integers in an array. I just don't understand how to receive to input from CodeChef .

Comment: I don't understand what it means by standard input.

Comment: I'm assuming it means from a standard text file.

Comment: Actually the way codechef works Scanner is too slow and Bufferedreader must be used.

Comment: You should check out the Sample solutions http://www.codechef.com/wiki/sample-solutions#Java
That should help you get started.

Comment: Use bufferedReader and Writer to make your java code I/O fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reader and writer class. Simple ones are `Scanner` and `PrintWriter`. And you need a `File` object

```
File inFile = new File("infilepath.txt");
File outFile = new File("outfilepath.txt");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

while (scanner.hasNext()){
    1. read input
    2. check if input is = to 42; if so, break
    3. if not print to outFile
}
```

Remember to throw exception or `try/catch`

**Edit:**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I think that the input is System.in, if that makes sense?

Comment: I don't think so. The instructions say from a .txt file. Maybe you get the file name from the System.in

Comment: You use the scanner to scan the file instead of the console.

Comment: For all the questions on our site, the input will be given to you from standard input (stdin for C users) and the result is expected on standard output (stdout for C users). This is the same as writing a program that accepts input from the keyboard and displays the results on the screen.

Comment: Is the section on I/O?

Comment: Yes, its the very first question on Codechef

Comment: Do they provide you with the txt file? Or a file name to use?

Comment: No, you submit the program and they input and check the output,The instructions are a bit vague, at least to me.

Comment: Do you have a link to the problem?

Comment: I don't get it. Do they just want you to write the loop?

Comment: The want you to take the input, write the loop and output the result.The loop is easy I just don't understand the I/O part

Comment: I think you're right. `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: See my edit at the bottom. I think that's all they want. You scan as if the site is giving you the input values. You read them one by one and print them when necessary inside the loop. Since you don't know how many inputs there are, you use a while loop

Comment: There tutorial is very confusing, on another page it says a txt file. Anyway I think I get it now thanks for you help, sorry if my qusetion was misleading..

Comment: I edited the question so I will hopefully be more helpful for people that had the same problem as me

Answer (score 0):

in C

```
int n=0;
while (1 == scanf("%d\n", &n)){
    if(n==42){
        break;
    }else{
        printf("%d\n",n);
    }
}
```

Comment: He's specifically asking for Java on CodeChef. Not C on console.

Answer (score -1):

there is no need to complicate anything.just remember, as the FAQ section says there should not be any statements like - "enter your number" or something like that.
you can use anything to receive input from it, **BufferedReader or Scanner both will work just fine**. let me give you the answer to your problem-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            n = s.nextInt();
            if (n!=42)
                System.out.println(n);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```